# What does this MATLAB expression mean?

Tags: matlab

I have the following MATLAB function definition:

```
function dv = rc(t,v)
dv(1) = -0.1*v(1);
```

I'm trying to understand what it's doing. I can understand the expression and definition of the function, but why is there a `(1)` after `dv` and `v`? What does that do?

Comment: `v(1)` refers to the first element of vector `v` and same for `dv(1)`

Comment: The parameter `t` is useless (not called in the function) and if length(v) = 1 you can simply write dv = -0.1*v. but in that case a function is not needed

Comment: See: [matrix indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) in MATLAB's language fundamentals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v(1)` takes the *first* element of `v` if `v` is not a scalar (note that Matlab indices starts from 1 and not from 0).
The output of `-0.1*v(1)` is assigned to `dv`, specifically to the first element of `dv`, that is `dv(1)`.
Note that since `dv` is not defined and is created by the assignment expression it is quite pointless to add the subscript `(1)` for this assignment.